# Microsoft oauth login stopped working all of a sudden?

Tags: oauth, microsoft-live-connect

I use Oauth via Microsoft and it has worked fine for a while, then a couple of weeks ago (can't remember exactly when) i got some tweet or something from someone saying that they had problems signing in with MS Oauth.

The error i get is this.

*https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=invalid_request&error_description=The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+'redirect_uri'+is+not+valid.+The+expected+value+is+'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'+or+a+URL+which+matches+the+redirect+URI+registered+for+this+client+application.*

The page actually says

"**We're unable to complete your request**

*Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.*"

And that indicates that they may actually have some issues but i think it's been like this for a while so i suspect it's just some generic error.

If i look at my request it says.

*client_id=[MY CLIENT ID]&scope=wl.basic&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[http://dev.ohso.se/login/ExternalLoginCallback/?**provider**=microsoft&**sid**=[some](http://dev.ohso.se/login/ExternalLoginCallback/?__provider__=microsoft&__sid__=[some) id]*

I do get the same error on both my dev app and the production app i have setup.

[image]

This is how my callback URLs look like. I have tried to add URLS both with ExternalLoginCallback and externallogincallback but it doesn't seems to work. It looks like it's saved but it's gone when you return to the page.

Anyone know how to contat MS to at least report this bug and maybe also get hold of someone that can help debug my problem?

/Ola

Comment: "Enhanced redirection security" is enabled or disabled (check you app details in MS Site)?

Comment: It worked like a charm when i turned off "Enhanced redirection security", as far as i remember i use kind of standard tools (from MS) to set this up, have any idea what i should do to be able to have this fancy enhanced security thingy ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it. The issue is with your request URL, remove `/` character from `..back/?provid...`. Your request URL should be

> client_id=[MY CLIENT ID]&scope=wl.basic&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://dev.ohso.se/login/ExternalLoginCallback?provider=microsoft&sid=[some id]

and you can have any redirect URL @MS

```
http://dev.ohso.se/login/ExternalLoginCallback
```

or

```
http://dev.ohso.se/login/ExternalLoginCallback/
```